# Add a class to div when a bootstrap div is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I add a class to a div when a bootstrap 3 collapsible is collapsed? I need a code which adds the class `darken` when the div is collapsed. And when a collapsible is closed the class `darken` should be removed

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe use show.bs.collapse or shown.bs.collapse events. Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-events

Comment: can you give ma an example?

Answer (score 1):

Use `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` to check when is collapsed/opened:

```js
$('#collapse1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   $("#content").addClass("darken")
});

$('#collapse1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $("#content").removeClass("darken")
});
```

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have solution with pure CSS

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}

#collapse1.in + #content {
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```

Comment: Thats cool to make it only with css but this will not work if #content is in any other place in the body.

Comment: It's because `+` refers to element placed immediately after `#collapse1`. You can use `~` instead of `+`, then you can put some html between `#collapse1` and `#content` and it will be still working

Answer (score 1):

With CSS, and assuming you want to darken rather than specifically needing to add a `.darken` class:

```
.collapse.in + #content {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

where `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "#switch" ).click(function() {
  if($("#collapse1" ).hasClass("in")) {
    $("#content" ).removeClass("darken");
  } else {
    $("#content" ).addClass("darken");
  }
});
```

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" id="switch"> Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```

Comment: I think you gave the right solution but shouldn't it be: `$("#content").removeClass("darken");` and `$("#content").addClass("darken");` instead of `collapse1`?

Comment: @Abbas Thanks for pointing out this issue. I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$('#content').toggleClass('darken')
})
})
```

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#collapse1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $("#content").addClass('darken')
})
$('#collapse1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $("#content").removeClass('darken')
})
```

```css
#content { 
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px; 
border: 3px solid #EEE;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center 
}

.darken { 
background: #EEE; 
color: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a id="myCollapsible" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Switch</a>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Power on.
</div>  
<div id="content">
Please, add the class "darken" to me!
</div>
```